# Weird behaviour of HttpWebRequest while using WebProxy

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, webproxy

I have an HttpWebRequest with a StreamReader that works very fine without using a WebProxy. When I use WebProxy, the StreamReader reads strange character instead of the actual html. Here is the code.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://URL");
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10";
req.Accept = "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
req.Method = "GET";
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("proxyIP:proxyPort");
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxyUser", "proxyPass");
req.Proxy = this.proxy;
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Without using the `WebProxy`, the variable `html` holds the expected html string from the URL. But with a `WebProxy`, `html` holds a value like that:

> "�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0��]r����s�Y����\0\tP\"]ki�*��ػ��-��X�\0\f���/�!�HU���>Cr���P$%�nR�� z�g��3�t�~q3�ٵȋ(M���14&?\r�d:�ex�j*��p������.��Y��o�|��ӎu�OO.�����\v]?}�~������E:�b��Lן�Ԙ6+�l���岳�Y��y'ͧ��~#5ϩ�it�2��5��%�p��E�L����t&x0:-�2��i�C���$M��_6��zU�t.J�>C-��GY��k�O�R$�P�T��8+�*]HY\"���$`Ō�-�r�ʙ`�H3\f8Jd���Q(:�G�E���r���Rܔ�*ڨ�����W�<]$����i>8\b�p� �\= 4\f�> �&��$��\v*��C��C�vC��x�p�|\"b9�ʤ�\r%i��w@��\t�r�M�� �����!�G�jP�8.D�k�Xʹt�J��/\v!�r��y\f7<����\",\a�/IK���ۚ�r�����ҿ5�;���}h��+Q��IO]�8��c����n�AGڟu2>�

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are passing

```
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
```

I would say your proxy compress the stream before sending it back to you.

Inspect the headers of the Response to check the encoding.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` doesn't even support sdch. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Gzip to decompress it.